# Student doubts about maximmization

Tags: optimization, kalman-filter

I am an economics student and I am having doubts about optimization.

For example, at some point in my course I will estimate a state space model via kalman filter and I will need to find parameters that maximize a probability distribution function (Normal, t student and etc).

I would like to know what mathematics/methods I need to learn/know to deal with this type of problem, to maximize those functions and find the parameters that I need?

Any reading, course would be very welcome.

I'm out of direction.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finding a parameter that optimizes an objective function (in this case, the likelihood or the posterior function) is known as constrained optimization. The constraint comes from the range of values that the parameter can take.

Denote $D$ as the data set, we solve the following problem

$$\max_\theta f(\theta| D)$$

subject to $\theta \in \Theta$.

[Here](https://www3.nd.edu/~jstiver/FIN360/Constrained%20Optimization.pdf) is an example of note on constrained optimizaiton.

In the event that $\Theta=\mathbb{R}^n$, then the problem is known as unconstrained optimization and it is advisable to study that before studying constrained optimization as usually that serve as the foundation. Langrangian techniques are usually used to relax a constrained optimization to an unconstrained optimizaiton.

When $f$ is concave and $\Theta$ is convex, we have a convex optimization problem.

Numerical method wise, steepest descent, stochastic gradient descent, Newton's method could be a start.